# Enhancing blob detection in image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

I have an image with varying brightness across the image. I wanted to predict all the dots present in the image. Converted the image into grayscale and applied `THRESH_BINARY_INV` and `THRESH_OTSU` to obtain the binary image. Then performed connected component analysis and created a mask to filter out the small components. Because of the varying brightness the `cv2.simpleBlobDetector()` was not able to find all the dots in the image even after tuning its parameters.

Another approach that involves brightening and converting the image to gray scale and then fine tuning the threshold to obtain the binary image. Which then passed to LoG, DoG and DoH detectors to find all the dots in the image. Found Determinant of Hessian (DoH) seems to perform well so fine tuned its parameter which gave a better a result than that of the `cv2.simpleBlobDetector()`. However it could not find all the dots in the image. It would be great and helpful if someone has some insights to share that could be useful. Please find below a sample of the picture to be processed.

The code for the different types of detectors:

```py
# Blob detection algorithms
blobs_log = blob_log(binary_image, max_sigma=20, num_sigma=10, threshold=.05)
blobs_log[:, 2] = skimage.feature.blobs_log[:, 2] * np.sqrt(2)

blobs_dog = blob_dog(binary_image, max_sigma=20, threshold=.1)
blobs_dog[:, 2] = skimage.feature.blobs_dog[:, 2] * np.sqrt(2)

blobs_doh = skimage.feature.blob_doh(binary_image, max_sigma=20, threshold=.03)
```

The image to be processed:
[image]

Results. The blue dots represents the target to be detected and the red circles encircling the dots represent it has been detected by the detector:
[image: The blue dots represents the target to be detected and the red circles encircling the dots represent it has been detected by the detector]

Image generated by adjusting the **sigma value** to **0.65**.

```
blob_doh(binary_image,min_sigma=0.65,threshold=.0325)
```

[image]

**Convert to LAB and threshold on the B channel.**

```
# Convert the image to LAB color space
lab_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)

# Extract the B channel (representing the blue-yellow axis)
b_channel = lab_image[:, :, 2]

# Define a threshold value (adjust as needed)
threshold_value = 75  # You can adjust this threshold value

# Apply thresholding on the B channel to make blobs darker than the background
binary_image = cv2.threshold(b_channel, threshold_value, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

cv2_imshow(binary_image)
```

[image]

```
#Find contours in the binary image
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binary_image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Create a copy of the original image to draw circles
result_image = img.copy()

# Draw red circles around the detected dots on the result image
for contour in contours:
    # Calculate the center and radius of the minimum enclosing circle
    (x, y), radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(contour)
    center = (int(x), int(y))
    radius = int(radius)
    
    # Draw a red circle with a thickness of 2
    cv2.circle(result_image, center, radius, (0, 0, 255), 1)

# Display the result
cv2_imshow(result_image)
```

[image]

Using the doh detector for the same LAB converted image.

```
from skimage.feature import blob_doh
blobs = blob_doh(binary_image,min_sigma=0.65,threshold=.0325)

# Scale the blob coordinates to match the original image size
blobs[:, 0] *= img.shape[1] / binary_image.shape[1]
blobs[:, 1] *= img.shape[0] / binary_image.shape[0]

# Draw circles around the detected blobs on the result image
for blob in blobs:
    y, x, r = blob
    cv2.circle(img, (int(x), int(y)), int(r), (0, 0, 255), 1)  # Draw a red circle with a thickness of 2

# Display the result image with detected blobs
cv2_imshow(img)
```

[image]

Comment: You could try to split the image into small overlapping patches and then try thresholding and connected components again. If patches are small enough, lighting variations should be small as well. Overlapping patches will help avoid slicing blobs at patch boundaries

Comment: You said you tried Laplacian of Gaussian and Determinant of Hessian, but you're not showing your code, so we can't tell if you used it appropriately or not. Also please provide the original image, without annotations.

Comment: Are you processing JPEG images, or is this something specific for uploading here? (I know SO will convert an image to JPEG if it's too big). The JPEG image has significant compression artifacts (especially since blue is mistreated harshly by JPEG because our eyes can't tell the difference). These artifacts make dot detection a lot harder than it needs to be. If you are actually using JPEG images, my recommendation would be to reduce the compression, or remove the color before compression. Ideally you'd be using uncompressed TIFF files for this.

Comment: Next, note that the sigma parameter to LoG and DoG and DoH relate to the sizes of the dots to detect. These dots are tiny, and all the same size, approximately matching a Gaussian with sigma of 2. You don't need a multi-scale approach, use a single scale, and set the sigma to 2.

Comment: Convert to LAB and threshold on the B channel.  Your blobs should be darker than the background.

Comment: I use only png files for processing

Comment: I tried setting min_sigma to a lesser value and the threshold for the gray image to be 0.08.
blobs = blob_doh(binary_image,min_sigma=0.65,threshold=.0325)

Still am not able to detect the dots in the top. Also some overlapping dots are considered as one.

Answer (score 1):

Varying brightness makes thresholding difficult. You can try to threshold the image segment by segment (e.g. 40x40 pixel) with an adaptive thresholding. This will preserve points in bright and dark areas.

You can also try to blur the image with a Gaussian blur and a large kernal. You can use the result to compensate for the brightness cone in the original image.